# Nginx regex match

Tags: nginx

I've got this simple requirement to add `max-age` header to all pages except home page.

```
location ~* ^/(.+)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=86400";
        }
```

This regular expression sjould work but Nginx is ignoring:

```
$ echo "/blog/pos1" | egrep "^/(.+)$" && echo "MATCH" || echo "NO MATCH"
/blog/pos1
MATCH
$ echo "/" | egrep "^/(.+)$" && echo "MATCH" || echo "NO MATCH"
NO MATCH
$ echo "" | egrep "^/(.+)$" && echo "MATCH" || echo "NO MATCH"
NO MATCH
```

**Config:**

```
server {

    listen      80;
    root        /var/www/html/test;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name tmp.local;

    location = /favicon.ico {
    return 204;
    }


location ~ ^/. {
        expires 86400s;
        }


location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    deny  all;
    }

location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|swf|flv|mp3)$ {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    expires 1209600s;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "DENY";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make the regexp a lot more efficient by just matching one character after the /: `^/.` Also try replacing the add_header with `expires 86400s`.

Comment: It probably matches, but what you wrote is completely wrong. Either this location would be ignored (because nginx find better one) or will ruin all your config. Show full nginx config for this server.

Comment: @AlexeyTen I added config as requested

Comment: With this config you effectively disabled PHP…

Comment: @wurtel why did you recommend to use `expires`? I still have to add `Cache-Control public` header and this casue that there are two separate `Cache-Control` headers instead of one.

Comment: `Cache-Control public` is the default behaviour in lieu of anything overriding it. Is there?

Comment: @wurtel I think `add_header` is better here: `Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400` vs. three separate headers for `Cache-Control: public`, `Cache-Control: max-age=86400`, `Expires:...` besides `expires` has to be computed for every date.